# Why can't I save my file like this? Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What's wrong with this at the exportpdf level? It saves the first file correctly but bugs out after that. I have cut out most of the macro just in case there is some stuff in there that looks unneeded.

```
Sub ptSub()
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
        thisFile = Cells(i, 3).Value
        ChDir "C:\IntelPT"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\IntelPT\" & _
            thisFile & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            False
        Next i
    End Sub
```

If I have just this

```
 "C:\IntelPT\" & _
                i & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,
```

It works how I want it to but I dont want an iterator as the filename

Comment: *"but bugs out after that"* - what is your error message?

Comment: Does this abbreviated version of your code have the same error message as the original?

Comment: What is the value of `thisFile`?

Comment: Runtime error - Document not saved

Comment: @Mistella ok good point I did not try that. If I replace thisfile with just i it works fine so I did not think about that.... is this because the workbook the file value is in is not activated?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you only need to do the `ChDir "C:\IntelPT"` once, so it could be moved above the For loop. tbh, not sure why you need it at all, since you are specifying the output folder in your filename.

Comment: Did you check that `thisFile` doesn't have characters that aren't allowed in a file name?

Comment: I just have sample values set right now as filename1, filename2... etc...

Comment: Be specific with all your Range/Cells references - you should include the workbook and the worksheet; even if you're assuming it's the active workbook/sheet, you should spell it out.  And why are you exporting the same sheet multiple times?  Is this your *actual* code?

Comment: Can you check if you're getting the desired value at "thisfile"? Something seems off, you have thisFile = Cells(i, 3).Value, but your max row is based on column B, lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 0):

Are your this file contents in Column B or C? The code works, but I think there was a mistake in your last row or the location of "thisfile" value. Always best for you to verify the value in the variable (thisfile), ensuring the desired value is obtained

If the file contents are in column B, this line:

```
        thisFile = Cells(i, 3).Value
```

should be changed to:

```
        thisFile = Cells(i, 2).Value
```

If the file contents are in column C, this line:

```
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

should be changed to:

```
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```